# How to call methods in 1st class to 2nd class with passing values

Tags: android, methods

I have MainActivity and SecondActivity. in main activity implemented a viewpager and in my SecondActivity i have button. when i click on button in SecondActivity 
 move to main activity and jump to spacific viewpager page.
Please provide suitable examples.

Comment: examples ?what u have tried please show some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: I tried this :
In main activity. Where i implemented ViewPager. 
public void pageJump(int page) {
 viewpager.setCurrentItem(page)
}
Then in 2nd activity in button click. 
MainActivity main=new MainActivity() ;
main.pageJump(50)
But it not worked even in my project when i call method 1 activity to another activity its also nor worken. App build without any error but when i test the app it is crashes on button click.

Answer (score 0):

In your code on button click write this line,

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity Name, TargetActivity.class).putExtras(tempBundle)
```

`tempBundle` is a Bundle argument for identify which position of the pager you want to display at current.

Then in your target Activity get the Bundle information, and set your ViewPager.

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0); //You can set your Bundle information 0 or 1 or 3
```

That time your ViewPager can set according to given position.

Comment: I tried this :
In main activity. Where i implemented ViewPager. 
public void pageJump(int page) {
 viewpager.setCurrentItem(page)
}
Then in 2nd activity in button click. 
MainActivity main=new MainActivity() ;
main.pageJump(50)
But it not worked even in my project when i call method 1 activity to another activity its also nor worken. App build without any error but when i test the app it is crashes on button click.

Answer (score 0):

We have Two ways

- Use Static Methods OR
- Use interface to communicate between activities and fragments also

[Communication through Interface](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments)